# Hook gets updated only for local build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-admin

I try to filter a list of objects from the context and put it into a `useList` hook so that I can use it in a `ListContextProvider` of `react-admin`.
When I let this component run locally with vite in development mode, everything works fine.

```js
import { DateField, Datagrid, useRecordContext, useList, ListContextProvider } from 'react-admin'
import { Box, Grid, LinearProgress } from '@mui/material'
import Client from 'types/Client'

const ListView = (): JSX.Element => {
  let record = useRecordContext<Client>()
  let loaded = Boolean(record.goals)

  console.log('Record: ', record)
  console.log('Goals', record.goals)
  console.log('Loaded', loaded)

  const filteredData = loaded ? record.goals.filter((goal) => goal.status === 2) : []
  console.log('Filtered goals', filteredData)
  let listContext = useList({
    data: filteredData,
    page: 0,
    perPage: 5,
  })

  console.log('Manual filter', loaded ? record.goals.filter((goal) => goal.status === 2) : [])
  console.log('ListContext', listContext.data)

  if (!loaded)
    return (
      <Box>
        <LinearProgress />
      </Box>
    )

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item lg={12}>
        <ListContextProvider value={listContext}>
          <Datagrid
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
          >
            <DateField label="Created At" source="createdAt" />  
          </Datagrid>
        </ListContextProvider>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default ListView
```

But when I deploy it in production mode the data in the `useList` hook gets overwritten by a second run. See the ListContext print in this screenshot, where the first one works as expected but then a second run appears with no elements:

[image: Production mode]

Why does this work locally, but not in production deployment?

Answer (score 1):

It's a small issue: Just set `page` to `1` or leave it out entirely and then it works again. The reason why it works locally and not in production was the strict mode of react, which is only enabled in local dev.